# GitLab permission denied connecting by ssh

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-7

I have a problem connecting to my GitLab account. I have generated the public key and added to my profile, but when I try to connect by ssh, it denies the permissions.

```
vicent@DARKNESS:~$ ssh git@gitlab.com
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (54.93.71.23)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is (myfingerprint).
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.com,54.93.71.23' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can directly login as git user on the `gitlab.com` server, which is not your own server, but the Gitlab's public instance one. If you want to push code to your repo hosted on gitlab.com through SSH, use git:

```
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:username_or_namespace/project_name.git
git push origin master
```